# Why is Chrome/Electron Devtools Perf showing almost nothing?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, electron

I have a React based Electron app and it runs attrociously slow for the first 15 seconds to 2-3 minutes of startup. I'm trying to track down the issue so I open the devtools, go to the 'Performance' tab and click the Record ● button. The bar showing how much of the recording memory has been used up fills up very quickly, much quicker than most apps so I stop it as soon as I can (between 1/8th and 1/4th then entire bar) usually in about 1 a second or less. Chrome/Electron then takes 30-40 seconds to parse/process the data before it show anything but when it finishes it shows almost nothing

[image]

Is there a known issue like this and a known workaround? A way to get more info out of devtools? Note that once the app is running smoothly I get more normal readings from devtools but fixing that first 2-3 minutes is turning out to be fairly difficult with no info.

[image]